# Command Line / Shell based rendering of URLs employing Javascript (Jive Server) for subsequent processing

Tags: javascript, bash, command-line, latex, render

I have the following situation.

We are using a LaTeX-based documentation system which needs to obtain information that is posted to a Jive (Clearspace) webpage.  This information is provided on a webpage in Javascript which cannot be properly rendered using conventional tools like cURL, wget, or lynx.

I am looking for some means to be able to do the following (bash/command line preferred)

1) Login to the Jive server with appropriate credentials (will probably need to save a cookie)
2) Access the specific page and dump the relevant information to a text file

Any ideas/suggestions?  I typically do most of these automated procedures using bash due to the fact that it makes integration with LaTeX (compiled with command line) much easier.  Yet, I am open to other routes with a bit of guidance.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to post and save cookies with wget (and presumably cURL). Here is an example from the wget man page:

```
 wget --save-cookies cookies.txt \
                        --post-data 'user=foo&password=bar' \
                        --keep-session-cookies
                        http://server.com/auth.php
```

You can them make the subsequent request to the page that displays the data with

```
 --load-cookie cookies.txt
```

As for figuring out what to put in the post-data option, I recommend installing a debugging proxy like [fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/). This will make it easy to understand the entire structure of the http messages sent to the server and allow you to reverse engineer the forms.

Comment: This may or may not answer OPs question, but this answers a question I've had for a year now (low priority). Great! thanks for fiddler2! Good luck to all.

Comment: The problem with wget is that it does not render the Javascript.

Comment: Why would it need to render? if javascript is rendering something on the client side, the data must be on the client side at some point, too. That means you can strip it out of the html or replicate whatever http requests the javascript is making to get the data by using fiddler2 to reverse engineer the request